Transaction signature verification failure
I'm coming to you with yet another Transaction signature verification failure. I read few other posts about it but it did not helped me (including adding prio fee ix)
Context:
I'm using anchor to call my program in my React App and signing the tx with phantom wallet results in invalid signature full decoded tx here
I'm certain that only 1 signature from the user is needed so other accounts involved in tx are not signers.
I also tried adding priority fee transaction but did not help

async function createAuction ( ... ) {

...


const ix = await program.methods         
  .initializeAuction3(                   
    <params>             
  )                                      
  .preInstructions([computeUnitLimitTx]) 
  .accounts(<accounts>)                    
  .instruction();                        

const result = await signAndSendTransaction( 
  ix,                                        
  wallet,                                    
  connection,                               
  true                                       
);                                           

}



async function signAndSendTransaction(
  ix: anchor.web3.TransactionInstruction,
  wallet: AnchorWallet,
  connection: Connection,
  withDebug: boolean = false
): Promise<{ txSig?: string; lastValidBlockHeight?: number }> {
  if (!ix || !wallet || !connection) {
    throw new Error(
      "[signAndSendTransaction] Err - ix/wallet/connection undefined"
    );
  }

  const PRIORITY_RATE = 100;
  const PRIORITY_FEE_IX = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: PRIORITY_RATE,
  });

  try {
    const { value: context } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext(
      "finalized"
    );
    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: context.blockhash,
      instructions: [ix, PRIORITY_FEE_IX],
    }).compileToLegacyMessage();
    const tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

    await wallet.signTransaction(tx);

    if (withDebug) {
      console.log(
        "[signAndSendTransaction][tx:]",
        Buffer.from(tx.serialize()).toString("base64")
      );
    }

    const sig = await connection.sendTransaction(tx);
    return {
      txSig: sig,
      lastValidBlockHeight: context.lastValidBlockHeight,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    const errMsg = err instanceof Error ? err.message : (err as string);
    console.error(errMsg);

    throw err;
  }
}


If I try to call my program via rpc method:
const sig = await program.methods         
  .initializeAuction3(                   
    <params>             
  )                                      
  .preInstructions([computeUnitLimitTx]) 
  .accounts(<accounts>)                    
  .rpc();  

Everything works fine.
What am I missing here?
Really appreciate your help!
